# POSIX runOnThread

Tags: c++, multithreading, posix

iOS SDK has a convinient Obj-C method `performSelectorOnMainThread` to ensure that a certain function will be executed on the main thread.

Android SDK has convinient Java method `runOnUIThread` that does the same.

I need something similar in C for POSIX thread. Does POSIX has it?

Comment: iOS and Android are operating systems.  POSIX is a threading library.  Those 'runOnUI' things assume a structure of inter-thread comms to allow functions to be signaled to other threads and those other threads being in a posiiton to receive the signals and call the functions.  An OS can provide that structure, POSIX can not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this works in Objective C and in Android is both of these environments have special threads running in these places that receive "run on" type of messages in order to perform the work. Each of these environments include a standardized run loop to make what you're talking about fairly transparent.

You can create this kind of behavior in your thread by having it listen for a message including a function pointer to run that function, but this is not a standard part of posix threading.